# Delete and add div by radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I choose the answer `"no"` the text box appears to the circumstances. If I change my mind and I will choose `"yes"` the text box disappears. But if I change again to `"no"` text box not appear again ...

Where I make mistake?

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2P5QJ/100/)

```
var numAdd = 1;
var add = function() {
    if (numAdd >= 2) return;
    $('#skoki').append('<div><input type="text" name="2" style="width: 100x; height: 300px;" /></div>');
     numAdd++;
};

function hideByClass(className) {
   $("."+className).remove();
};
```

Comment: The first time you hit the add function you make `numAdd` equal to 2, the second time you hit it `if (numAdd >= 2)` is true and will `return`. Doing something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sLor05c3/) will fix it. Is there any reason for the `numAdd` to exist?

Comment: You removed the element from the DOM so it's no longer there. Try using `hide` and `show` jQuery functions as it seems removing and re-adding is overkill.

Comment: You are required to post a complete, minimal example of the code problem here, not a jsfiddle that can change or disappear tomorrow, helping no one with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it by below code

```js
$(document).on('click', 'input.inp-rad', function(){
        if($(this).attr('data-val') == 'No'){
                $('#skoki').html('<div><input type="text" name="2" style="width: 200x; height: 36px;" /></div>');
    }else{
            $('#skoki').html('');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Do you like stack Overflow? If "No" tell me why.<br>
<input type="radio" name="a" class="inp-rad" data-val="Yes"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="a" class="inp-rad" data-val="No"><label>No</label>
<div id="skoki" class="blueBox"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

***Reason:-*** You are removing the whole div in your `hideByClass()` function so second time onward `add()` not working because `$('#skoki')` is undefined then.

Simply do it like below:-

```js
function add() {
    $('.blueBox').html('<div><input type="text" name="2" style="width: 100x; height: 300px;" /></div>');
};

function hideByClass(className) {
   $("."+className).html('');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Do you like stack Overflow? If "No" tell me why.<br>
<input type="radio" name="a" onclick="hideByClass('blueBox');"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="a" onclick="add()"><label>No</label>
<br>
<div id="skoki" class="blueBox"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're removing the parent element instead of just the input itself. What you should do instead is either remove the children, or simply clear the HTML. You also have a condition in there that doesn't let the input be added again. So you need to reset that back to 1 in order for the input to be added back in.

```js
var numAdd = 1;
var add = function() {
    if (numAdd >= 2) return;
    $('#skoki').append('<div><input type="text" name="2" style="width: 100x; height: 300px;" /></div>');
     numAdd++;
};

function hideByClass(className) {
   $("."+className).html('');
   numAdd = 1;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Do you like stack Overflow? If "No" tell me why.<br>
<input type="radio" name="a" onclick="hideByClass('blueBox');"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="a" onclick="add()"><label>No</label>
<div id="skoki" class="blueBox">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numAdd = 1;
var add = function() {
    $('#skoki').append('<div class="blueBox"><input type="text" name="2" style="width: 100x; height: 300px;" /></div>');
  
};

function hideByClass(className) {
   $("."+className).remove();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Do you like stack Overflow? If "No" tell me why.<br>
<input type="radio" name="a" onclick="hideByClass('blueBox');"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="a" onclick="add()"><label>No</label>
<div id="skoki">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have altered your code a little bit to the following and it works.

```
Do you like stack Overflow? If "No" tell me why.<br>
<input type="radio" name="a" onclick="hideByClass('input');"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="a" onclick="openByClass('blueBox')"><label>No</label>
<div id="skoki" class="blueBox">
    </div>
```

Your Javascript

```
function hideByClass(className) {
   $("."+className).remove();
};

function openByClass(className){
    $("."+className).append('<div class="input"><input type="text" name="2" style="width: 300px; height: 35px;" /></div>');
};
```